# About the way streaming with gstreamer

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

Should I send video and audio separately when streaming with gstreamer? Can't I send video and audio as an one thing(like mp4 or avi)?

Answer (score 0):

You can stream audio/video together for example with mpegtsmux and send it via udp.. you can do this with any container.. also with for example mkv but you must catch the beginning of stream on the client side because there are the metadata necessary to begin the playback..

So the idea is - encode, mux, chop/merge (..payload), stream via udp/tcp ..

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! voaacenc ! mpegtsmux name=mux videotestsrc ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mux. mux. ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=6666
```

You can open in vlc as stream `udp://@:6666`

There is also HLS (avmux_hls) and other protocols suitable for streaming - though I never used them..

Comment: Can I send and receive it via tcp??

Comment: @Potato of course .. you have tcpserversink/tcpclientsrc etc .. although I never used them.. also for instance the rtspsrc has procol attribute which can be set to tcp (it works better that way for me).. you must realise that with tcp you can address usually just one host.. or it is on demand like rtsp .. with udp you can do multicast an such things